# How to add dots under horizontal RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView which show images as i want

```
    RecyclerView detailsRecycleImage = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailsRcycleImage);
     RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
      getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
      LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
      false
    );

    detailsRecycleImage.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    ImagesAdapter imgAdapter = new 
    ImagesAdapter(getActivity(),contactsData.getContactImages());
    detailsRecycleImage.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
```

And my adapter code is

```
     public class ImagesAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<ImagesAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
  private Context cnt;
  public ArrayList<String> imgsUrls;
  public ImagesAdapter(Context cnt, ArrayList<String> imgsUrls) {
    this.cnt=cnt;
    this.imgsUrls=imgsUrls;
  }

  @Override
  public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_img,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String singleImg = imgsUrls.get(position);
    Picasso.with(cnt).load(singleImg).into(holder.img);
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return imgsUrls.size();
  }


  public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView img;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
      super(view);
      img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
    }
  }
}
```

And my layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/img"
          />
</RelativeLay
```

I just need to add dots under the recyclerview as an indicator as this image
   [image]
[image]
Is there any way to add something to my code and get this view ?

Comment: you have to make custom layout that has textview as dot background

Comment: example or more details please

Comment: check this link. the used with Viewpager but you can set with recyclerview:  http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

Comment: you should use Viewpager instead of recyclerview to show your images in full screen. With this these navigation indicators integration will be easy for you.

Comment: Have a look at this  https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5462

Comment: please check this blog it may help you.https://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2017/06/24/viewpager-recyclerview.html

Answer (score 20):

I slightly change LinePagerIndicatorDecoration to make it DotsIndicatorDecoration and to support both GridLayoutManager and LinearLayoutManager

```
public class DotsIndicatorDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final int indicatorHeight;
    private final int indicatorItemPadding;
    private final int radius;

    private final Paint inactivePaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint activePaint = new Paint();

    public DotsIndicatorDecoration(int radius, int padding, int indicatorHeight, @ColorInt int colorInactive, @ColorInt int colorActive) {
        float strokeWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density * 1;
        this.radius = radius;
        inactivePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        inactivePaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        inactivePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        inactivePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        inactivePaint.setColor(colorInactive);

        activePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        activePaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        activePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        activePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        activePaint.setColor(colorActive);

        this.indicatorItemPadding = padding;
        this.indicatorHeight = indicatorHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(@NotNull Canvas c, @NotNull RecyclerView parent, @NotNull RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state);

        final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = parent.getAdapter();

        if (adapter == null) {
            return;
        }

        int itemCount = adapter.getItemCount();

        // center horizontally, calculate width and subtract half from center
        float totalLength = this.radius * 2 * itemCount;
        float paddingBetweenItems = Math.max(0, itemCount - 1) * indicatorItemPadding;
        float indicatorTotalWidth = totalLength + paddingBetweenItems;
        float indicatorStartX = (parent.getWidth() - indicatorTotalWidth) / 2f;

        // center vertically in the allotted space
        float indicatorPosY = parent.getHeight() - indicatorHeight / 2f;

        drawInactiveDots(c, indicatorStartX, indicatorPosY, itemCount);

        final int activePosition;

        if (parent.getLayoutManager() instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
            activePosition = ((GridLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        } else if (parent.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
            activePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        } else {
            // not supported layout manager
            return;
        }

        if (activePosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            return;
        }

        // find offset of active page if the user is scrolling
        final View activeChild = parent.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(activePosition);
        if (activeChild == null) {
            return;
        }

        drawActiveDot(c, indicatorStartX, indicatorPosY, activePosition);
    }

    private void drawInactiveDots(Canvas c, float indicatorStartX, float indicatorPosY, int itemCount) {
        // width of item indicator including padding
        final float itemWidth = this.radius * 2 + indicatorItemPadding;

        float start = indicatorStartX + radius;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            c.drawCircle(start, indicatorPosY, radius, inactivePaint);
            start += itemWidth;
        }
    }

    private void drawActiveDot(Canvas c, float indicatorStartX, float indicatorPosY,
                               int highlightPosition) {
        // width of item indicator including padding
        final float itemWidth = this.radius * 2 + indicatorItemPadding;
        float highlightStart = indicatorStartX + radius + itemWidth * highlightPosition;
        c.drawCircle(highlightStart, indicatorPosY, radius, activePaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(@NotNull Rect outRect, @NotNull View view, @NotNull RecyclerView parent, @NotNull RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        outRect.bottom = indicatorHeight;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        RecyclerView recyclerView = resourceLayout.getSuccessView().findViewById(R.id.cardsRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(manageCardGenericAdapter);
        final int radius = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.radius);
        final int dotsHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dots_height);
        final int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.primaryBlue);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DotsIndicatorDecoration(radius, radius * 4, dotsHeight, color, color));
        new PagerSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Comment: how do we make the dots appear above the recycler view?

Answer (score 11):

Check this out: 
https://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2017/06/24/viewpager-recyclerview.html

Tldr: 
Create a [LinePagerIndicatorDecoration](https://github.com/bleeding182/recyclerviewItemDecorations/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/bleeding182/recyclerviewdecorations/viewpager/LinePagerIndicatorDecoration.java) and add it to our RecyclerView:

```
// pager indicator
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new LinePagerIndicatorDecoration());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: How to change position of dots indicator

Answer (score 5):

I've tried decisions with decorator - strange behaviour: my horizontal recyclerview does not stick to edges of screen. check out my decision -

```
        recycler.setAdapter(recyclerViewHorizontalAdapter);
        recycler.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            int currentCompletelyVisibleLab = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerViewLayoutManager).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            bottomDotsTransaction(currentCompletelyVisibleLab);
        }
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        }
    });
    addBottomDots();
    setLabsOnTouchListener(commercialLabsNames, availableTests);
}
//create empty linear layout below recyclerview and add dots to it
private void addBottomDots() {
    ImageView imageView;
    for (int i = 0; i < commercialLabsLogos.size(); i++) {
        imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_dot_4dp);
        imageView.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
        dotsLinearLayout.addView(imageView);
    }
    bottomDotsTransaction(0);
}
private void bottomDotsTransaction(int pos) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dotsLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (dotsLinearLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageView) {
            ((ImageView) dotsLinearLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_dot_4dp);
        }
    }
    //Set the chosen dot on position
    ((ImageView) dotsLinearLayout.getChildAt(pos)).setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_dot_6dp);
}
```

you just need to set OnScrollListener and inside its callback re-define your linearlayout with dots via your layout_manager and methods

```
    .findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
or
    .findLastVisibleItemPosition()
    .findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
```